# Add format to datatable conflicts with action buttons in R shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I have used the directions in [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45739303/r-shiny-handle-action-buttons-in-data-table/45739826#45739826) to create a `datatable` with buttons inside.

I added some formatting to the `renderTable()` call to highlight in yellow `motivation == 3`

```
    output$data <- DT::renderDataTable(
      datatable(df$data) %>% formatStyle(
        'Motivation',
        target = 'row',
        backgroundColor = styleEqual(c(3), c('yellow'))
      ),
      server = FALSE, escape = FALSE, selection = 'none'
    )
```

This highlights the correct row:

[image]

The problem is that color formatting messes up with the buttons. I find the same problem when trying to format dates (datatable automatically shows them in UTC and I want them on local time). Are both formatting and buttons inside the table incompatible?

I get the following warning

```
renderDataTable ignores ... arguments when expr yields a datatable object; see ?renderDataTable
```

Here's the code for the app:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

shinyApp(
  ui <- fluidPage(
    DT::dataTableOutput("data"),
    textOutput('myText')
  ),

  server <- function(input, output) {

    myValue <- reactiveValues(employee = '')

    shinyInput <- function(FUN, len, id, ...) {
      inputs <- character(len)
      for (i in seq_len(len)) {
        inputs[i] <- as.character(FUN(paste0(id, i), ...))
      }
      inputs
    }

    df <- reactiveValues(data = data.frame(

      Name = c('Dilbert', 'Alice', 'Wally', 'Ashok', 'Dogbert'),
      Motivation = c(62, 73, 3, 99, 52),
      Actions = shinyInput(actionButton, 5, 'button_', label = "Fire", onclick = 'Shiny.onInputChange(\"select_button\",  this.id)' ),
      stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
      row.names = 1:5
    ))


    output$data <- DT::renderDataTable(
      datatable(df$data) %>% formatStyle(
        'Motivation',
        target = 'row',
        backgroundColor = styleEqual(c(3), c('yellow'))
      ),
      server = FALSE, escape = FALSE, selection = 'none'
    )

    observeEvent(input$select_button, {
      selectedRow <- as.numeric(strsplit(input$select_button, "_")[[1]][2])
      myValue$employee <<- paste('click on ',df$data[selectedRow,1])
    })


    output$myText <- renderText({

      myValue$employee

    })

  }
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43924450/11598948). Applying his advice to your problem, I move `escape = FALSE, selection = 'none'` in `datatable(df$data)` and it works (you need to remove `server = FALSE`, which is not accepted in `datatable`):

```
    output$data <- DT::renderDataTable(
      datatable(df$data, escape = FALSE, selection = 'none') %>% formatStyle(
        'Motivation',
        target = 'row',
        backgroundColor = styleEqual(c(3), c('yellow'))
      )
    )
```

In case the answer I refer above is deleted (don't know if it can be), I also put it here:

> You are getting this error because you are returning a `DT::datatable` **AND** you are also specifying `filter='top'` as one of the `...` arguments to `DT::renderDataTable`. As the message is trying to tell you `...` arguments are ignored since you are returning a `DT::datatable`. This is because the `...` arguments are intended to be passed through to the `DT:datatable` constructor.
>
> Either move `filter='top'` inside the `DT::datatable` constructor or return a `data.frame` and the `filter='top` will be used when `DT::renderDataTable` constructs a `DT::datatable` with your specified `data.frame`.