# Warning in processWidget(instance) using renderDataTable and Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, datatable, dt

I am getting this warning every time I run my `shiny` App.

> Warning in processWidget(instance) :   renderDataTable ignores ...
> arguments when expr yields a datatable object; see ?renderDataTable

This is a reproducible example:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
                titlePanel("My app"),
                sidebarLayout(
                  sidebarPanel(
                  ),
                  mainPanel(
                    dataTableOutput("table")
                    )
                )
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$table <- renderDataTable({

      datatable(
        mtcars,
        filter = list(position = 'top', clear = FALSE),
        selection = "none", #this is to avoid select rows if you click on the rows
        rownames = FALSE,
        extensions = 'Buttons',
        
        options = list(
          scrollX = TRUE,
          autoWidth = TRUE,
          dom = 'Blrtip',
          buttons =
            list('copy', 'print', list(
              extend = 'collection',
              buttons = list(
                list(extend = 'csv', filename = "file", title = NULL),
                list(extend = 'excel', filename = "file", title = NULL)),
              text = 'Download'
            )),
          lengthMenu = list(c(10, 30, 50, -1),
                            c('10', '30', '50', 'All'))
        ),
        class = "display"
      )
    
  },rownames=FALSE)
}
  
  
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I checked this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36096505/r-shiny-widgetfunc-warning-messages-with-eventreactivewarning-1-and-renderda) but I am not using the parameter `filter` at the end. I am using it inside `DT::datatable`. What is more, if I comment this line (`filter = list(position = 'top', clear = FALSE)`), I am still getting the same warning. So it must be because of another reason.

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rownames` is not part of the arguments of `DT::renderDataTable()` so it is passed in `...` in this function. But the documentation of `DT::renderDataTable()` says:

> `...` [is] ignored when expr returns a table widget, and passed as additional arguments to datatable() when expr returns a data object

Here, you create a `datatable` in `renderDataTable()` so `...` (and hence `rownames = FALSE`) is ignored. This argument is useless here so you can remove `rownames = FALSE` and it will remove the warning.

Comment: Oh okay! Thanks very much! I didn't know that I couldn't use that parameter. However, if I wanted to show the `rownames` with `datatable`, is there a way to show them? (I thought to include them as a new column but...). Using  `output$table2 <- renderDataTable({
    mtcars
  }, rownames=T)` I can see the rownames... but with `datatable`... I don't know how to do it if I cannot use that parameter.

Comment: Then you could add `rownames = TRUE` in `datatable()`

Comment: Right, I forgot that I put the parameter, sorry. Thanks very much!